# Hide menu item according to user account

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On my login mysql table, i have an account type column. If the user has a Manager account type, i want to show a management menu item and if not hide it.

This is pretty simple but its not working:

In my header, i have the following:

```
<script>
var logged_in_account_type = "<?php echo $_SESSION['account_type'] ; ?>";
    if(logged_in_account_type === "Manager") {             
         document.getElementById('management_menu').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('management_menu').style.display = 'none';                          
    }
</script>
```

I tried without the echo has well.

```
<div id="management_menu" style="display:none">
  <li>
    <a href="index.php"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="mm-text">Dashboard</span></a>
  </li>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="text-bg"><span class="text-slim">Welcome,</span> <span class="text-semibold"><?php echo $_SESSION['account_type'] ?></span></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is the menu always showing? The menu never shows?

Comment: The menu is always hidden no matter what account is logged in.

Comment: Can you show us what `$_SESSION['account_type']` looks like? Could just be that you didn't store the value you thought you did.

Comment: JCD, you may accept any of the answers if it was useful to solve your problem (by clicking its checkmark).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using php **if** while rendering your menu? Something like this:

```
  <?php if($_SESSION['account_type'] == 'Manager'): ?>
<div id="management_menu">
 <ul>
  <li>
    <a href="index.php">Dashboard</a>
  </li>
    <li>
      <a href="index.php">Users</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>  
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i've +1 for using PHP

Comment: This is a much easier solution, thank you for your time.

Comment: @JCD Not a problem, glad i could help out. I would recommend using some template engines like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or better yet Laravel's [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade). But if you're not ready to switch to Laravel yet Twig will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your javascript code in the document? If your javascript code is on the top of the document, it possibly shows or hides the `<div>` element properly, but, because the `<div>` element is at the bottom of the document, it is hidden because its "style" says so.

The solution is to move the javascript code **below** the `<div>` element, this will solve the "execution order" problem you have. Example :

```
<div id="management_menu" style="display:none">
  <li>
    <a href="index.php"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="mm-text">Dashboard</span></a>
  </li>
</div>

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['account_type'] = "Manager";
?>

<script>
var logged_in_account_type = "<?php echo $_SESSION['account_type'] ; ?>";
    if(logged_in_account_type === "Manager") {             
         document.getElementById('management_menu').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('management_menu').style.display = 'none';                          
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you